# Find the number of elements in a quotient ring satisfying $a^2 = a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, idempotents

Let $f(T)=T^3+T^2+2T+2 \in \mathbb{Z}[T]$ and let $I$ be the ideal of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[T]$ generated by $f(T)$ and $5$. Find the number of elements $z \in \mathbb{Z}[T]/I$ such that $z^2=z$.

Some observations:

1. $\mathbb{Z}[T]/I \cong \{ aT^2 + bT + c \, | \, a,b,c \in
       \mathbb{Z}_5 \}$.
2. Now clearly $0$ and $1$ are solutions. Actually for every $z$, $c \in \{ 0, 1\}$
3. Beside $0$ and $1$, there is no solution such that $a \neq 0$

Now I wanted to test all the elements satisfying 2 and 3, but I am wondering if there is a faster solution, because the next exercise is to find all $z$ such that $z^{18} = 1$.

Comment: That polynomial is reducible mod $5$ as a product of a linear factor and an irreducible quadratic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your polynomial is reducible, write it as $T^3 + T^2 + 2T + 2 = (T + 1)(T^2 + 2)$. Note that these factors are also irreducible modulo $5$ so

$$\Bbb Z[T]/(5, f(T)) \cong \Bbb F_5[T]/(\overline{f}(T)) \cong \Bbb F_5 \times \Bbb F_{25}$$

by the Chinese remainder theorem.

Since this ring is finite, it is Artinian, so [there are](https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/tag/artinian-rings/) $2^m$ idempotent elements where $m$ is the number of maximal ideals of the ring. In a direct product $R \times S$ of rings, the only maximal ideals are those of the form $R \times \mathfrak{m}_S$ or $\mathfrak{m}_R \times S$.

In this case, $R = \Bbb F_5$ and $S = \Bbb F_{25}$, both fields. There are very few maximal ideals in fields, so this should give you what you need to count the maximal ideals of the product.

Comment: The fact that $\mathbb{F}_5 \times \mathbb{F}_{25} \cong \mathbb{Z}[T]/I$ is great for the exercise to count for $z^{18} = 1$ because you just have to check $(a, (c,d)) = (1, (1,1))$ with $a,c,d \in \mathbb{F}_5$.

Your solution for the first question is nice but it feels a bit over the top for me, but this is just a feeling.

Comment: @Sqyuli That $\Bbb Z[T]/(p, f(T)) \cong \Bbb F_p[T]/(\overline{f}(T))$ is one of those nice tricks that you'll remember in future. You might like to prove it. In fact I notice that you're asking a lot of algebraic number theory questions; this isomorphism is one way of looking at the ramification of rational primes in number fields.

Comment: May I shout: First isomorphism theorem with something like $\mathbb{Z}[T]$ -> $\mathbb{F}_p[T]/ ( \overline{f}(T))$

Comment: @Sqyuli it's actually with the 3rd isomorphism theorem, which is why you need to reduce $f(T)$